# Writing a qiskit code for a encryption problem

Tags: qiskit, programming

*Bob* wants to send his friend Alice a message in the form of a string of bits, *s*. In order to make it harder for an eavesdropper to read *s*, Bob does the following:

- Defines a function $ f: \{0,1\}^n → \{0,1\}, f(x) = ∑ s_ix_i \text{ } mod \text{ } 2$
- Creates a quantum circuit $ U_f$ that takes the state $|x⟩_n|y⟩_1$ to $|x⟩_n|y \oplus f(x)⟩_1$
- Bob encapsulates $U_f$ into a black box and delivers it to Alice. Alice is able to query the black box with a quantum state and get the output, but she cannot look at the circuit itself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It also sounds like you're asking us to do your homework.

Comment: It was a QC workshop question but I don't have enough knowledge to solve this one. Well they had given me a solution and I had to explain each step of it.